# Algorithm for Gram Schmidt in Julia

Tags: matrix, julia, linear-algebra, numerical-methods

How would one write a function that performs gram-schmidt orthogonalization on the columns of some matrix A? I am not sure how to write an algorithm or function in the Julia language that performs this for any given matrix A.

Comment: I wrote this a long time ago, so not sure how it will work now, but maybe helpful: https://github.com/jcrudy/GramSchmidt.jl

Comment: https://jutho.github.io/KrylovKit.jl/latest/man/algorithms/#KrylovKit.ClassicalGramSchmidt

Comment: Do a QR decomposition, the columns of the Q factor are the orthonormalized columns of the input matrix. This procedure should be readily available and is more numerically stable than Gram-Schmidt.

Comment: Here is an implementation : https://forem.julialang.org/vinodv/gram-schmidt-orthogonalization-with-julia-43ee